# A closed regular planar curve of constant width - finding an expression for the opposite point to $\alpha(s)$

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

A closed regular planar curve $C$ is said to have **constant width** $μ$ if the distance between any pair of parallel tangent lines to $C$ is always $μ$. If two points on $C$ have parallel tangent lines, call them **opposite**.

I've been able to show that the opposite point to $\alpha(s)$ is of the form $\beta(s) = \alpha(s) + \lambda(s) T(s) + \mu N(s),$ for some differentiable real function $\lambda$ defined on the same interval as $\alpha$. I want to show that $\lambda = 0$ everywhere. There are questions on the forum about the same problem, but I'm stuck on an earlier step in the proof.

I've struggled many hours (to my surprise), frustratingly, without producing anything of value. Either a hint or full answer would be welcome.

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get the expression for opposite points?

Comment: @Unknownx Good question. For each $s$, we have that $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ are linearly independent and hence span the plane. This implies that we may write $\beta(s) = \alpha(s) + \lambda(s) T(s) + \mu'(s) N(s)$ for some functions $\lambda, \mu'$. Because the tangent lines are a constant distance $\mu$ apart, and $N$ is perpendicular to $T$ (with $T$ per definition along the tangent line), the function $\mu'$ is constant $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Use what it means for $\beta(s)$ to be the point *opposite* to $\alpha(s)$. What does this tell you about $\beta'(s)$? Now calculate.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! So we have $\beta'(s)$ lies in the direction of $T(s),$ so $$\beta '(s) = \nu(s) T(s) = T(s) + \lambda'(s) T(s) + \lambda(s) \kappa(s) N(s) - \kappa(s) T(s).$$ $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ are linearly independent so their coefficients have to be zero. Since we were also given that $\kappa \neq 0$ everywhere (I forgot to say that), this means that $\lambda(s) = 0.$

Comment: There you go. This technique gets used a *lot*!

Comment: @NeckverseHerdman Why $\beta'(s)=\nu(s)T(s)$?

Comment: I know $r'(s)=T(s)$., if parameter is arc length.

Comment: @Unknownx per definition, $\beta'(s)$ is a vector along the tangent line in $\beta(s)$, and the line is parallel to the tangent line in $\alpha(s)$, and so $\beta'(s)$ and $T(s)$ (unit vector along tangent line in $\alpha(s)$) have to be parallel, and so a multiple of each other, which I denote by $\nu(s)$. Hope this helped. (Note that $\nu(s)$ is either 1 or -1, but I didn't really need that so I omitted it.)

Comment: No, actually, I didn’t pay attention ages ago. There is a negative since the opposite point has a parallel tangent line but is moving in the opposite direction. But the multiple of $-T(s)$ is the speed of $\beta$. Even if $\alpha$ is arclength-parametrized, rarely will $\beta$ also be.