# If $β(s)$ is opposite $α(s)$. Why $β(s) = α(s) + λ(s)T(s) + μN(s)$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

A closed, planar curve $C$ is said to have constant breadth $μ$ if the distance between parallel
tangent lines to $C$ is always $μ.$ Assume for the
rest of this problem that the curve is $C^2$ and $κ \neq 0.$

Prove that if $C$ has constant
breadth $μ,$ then the chord joining opposite points is normal to the curve at both points.

**My attempt:-**
Author gave us hint that  If $β(s)$ is opposite $α(s)$, then $β(s) = α(s) + λ(s)T(s) + μN(s)$. I really don't understand how did the author write like this. Please help me. After that I can do the problem using the hint in the given answer [A closed regular planar curve of constant width - finding an expression for the opposite point to $\alpha(s)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347921/a-closed-regular-planar-curve-of-constant-width-finding-an-expression-for-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ form a basis of the plane. The vector $\beta(s)-\alpha(s)$ is a linear combination:
$$
\beta(s)-\alpha(s)=\lambda(s)T(s)+\mu(s)N(s)
$$
But you know that the distance between the tangents, which is the normal component of the above vector, is fixed, $\mu(s)=\mu$.

Comment: what if the curve lies in the plane spanned by T(s) and B(s) oR B(s) and N(s)?

Comment: That is not possible. Your curve is planar, therefore $B$ is orthogonal to the plane of the curve, and any vector on its plane is a combination of $T$ and $N$ alone.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the definition.

Comment: Is it possible to prove  $\mu(s)=\mu$ a constant using analytic method? I understood the distance between the tangent line is $\mu$.

Comment: Actually when I draw the figure, I can see $\beta(s)-\alpha(s)$ has only normal direction.

Comment: Right. That is exactly the argument in the post you linked.$\lambda$ happens to be identically zero.

Comment: That is the analytic proof.